# How to clear the default value entered in calendar box and send a new date of birth

Tags: java, selenium, automation, cucumber, bdd

I want to sendKeys in the calendar box but there is a default value in that box

I tried to clear it before sendKeys but it is not working

My code:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
                            actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dateOfBirth']")));
                            actions.click();
                            actions. clear();
                            Thread.sleep(3000);     
                            actions.sendKeys("07-12-2018");
                            actions.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
                        actions.build().perform();
```

Please help me how to clear the box

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" value="07-14-1993" id="dateOfBirth" class="react-datepicker-ignore-onclickoutside">
```

Comment: Please show us this box, weblink or HTML code

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov Please see the html code in the updated question it has default value in it which i want to clear

Comment: What user have to do when he wants to change the date manually?

Comment: He has to select the date as in select the year and then date to change the date @AndreiSuvorkov

Comment: I understand that he have to select. What exactly means select? Click and then just type in input field, or click and will be opened something?

Comment: He can click on the box clear the default date by backspace and then enter the new date of birth thats all @AndreiSuvorkov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Actions` you can try:

```
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dateOfBirth']"));
input.click();
input.clear();
input.sendKeys("07-12-2018");
input.sendKeys(Keys.TAB); // I don't know why you need TAB, but since you have it in your code
```

or

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dateOfBirth']")));
actions.click();
actions.build().perform();
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dateOfBirth']"));
input.clear();
input.sendKeys("07-12-2018");
input.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

or

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);                        
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dateOfBirth']")));
actions.click();
actions.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE).sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE).sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE).sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE).sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE).sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE).sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE).sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE).sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE).sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
Thread.sleep(3000);     
actions.sendKeys("07-12-2018");
actions.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
actions.build().perform();
```

or use JavaScript:

```
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dateOfBirth']"));
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute(value, '07-12-2018')", input);
```

Comment: I tried this first but it is giving me an error that cannot focus on the element and that is why I am using action class

Comment: ok, you can use Actions to moveToelement and click on it, but then clear and senk keys separately. i have edited my answer, please have a look

Comment: Tried it but again its appending the sendkeys value with default value

Comment: Try one more suggestion in answer. Btw, why are you using TAB? Probably TAB causes this issue?

Comment: I tried all the solution it is clearing the default value but then its entering the default value and then my sendkeys value is appending to it

Comment: Have you tried javaScript executor as well? In my answer

Comment: Worked like a charmn with Backspace but I am sending backspace 10 times increasing my line of code.

Comment: @SarveshSingh yes, 10 times is a 'dirty' solution, but it works ))

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov : You can append all the back spaces in one line of code though , or else you can use loop also. Note that using loop will increase the complexity.

Comment: Something like : `actions.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE).sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE); ` or `actions.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE+Keys.BACK_SPACE)` , not sure about this one.

Comment: @cruisepandey thank you for feedback! I will edit my answer.